# flask session not working if I use mkdtemp() for SESSION_FILE_DIR

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask application in what I'm trying to create a session but only for the admin routes, so anywhere else can be accessible except admin routes, the thing is in my localhost everything works fine, but, in the live server, the session get created when I log in, but when I try to check if the session exist calling session.get("user_id"), it doesn't. Is like if the session is not created persistent. I have been reading for 10 hours today and I finally found why is not working, but I really don't undestand why it happens. The problem i'm facing is located in app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp(), if I use this in the localhost works, but not in the live server, and if I omite that line, then it works in the live server. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, jsonify, url_for
from flask_session import Session
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from tempfile import mkdtemp # used to create a temp directory
from helpers import login_required
import os

# Configure application as flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.secret_key = 'superkey'

# function to login admin
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
"""Log admin in"""

# Forget any user_id
session.clear()

# User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
if request.method == "POST":

    # Ensure username was submitted
    if not request.form.get("username"):
        flash ("must provide username")
        return render_template('/login.html')

    # Ensure password was submitted
    elif not request.form.get("password"):
        flash ("must provide password")
        return render_template('/login.html')

    # Query database for username
    username = request.form.get("username")
    username = str.lower(username)
    db = dbConnection()
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM identities WHERE user_name = ?", [username])
    rows = db.fetchall()

    # Ensure username exists and password is correct
    if len(rows) == 1:
        uid, name, pass_hash = rows[0]
    if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(pass_hash, request.form.get("password")):
        flash ("invalid username and/or password")
        return render_template('/login.html')

    # Remember which user has logged in
    session["user_id"] = uid

    # Redirect user to home page
    return redirect("/adminForms")

# User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
else:
    return render_template("login.html")

# function as decorator to ensure the user was logged in before 
# can go to a protected page
def login_required(f):

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        # if session don't return a value, then the user needs to log in
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            return redirect("/login")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: Can you print the path for `mkdtemp()` on your live server, then access that folder and see if you can add a test file to it. Use a simple Python script to write to that location and see if that works. The [docs for mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) say: _"The directory is readable, writable, and searchable only by the creating user ID."_

Comment: Don't really know what is going on here, but I tried what you said, and when I uncomment the problem code line, it also worked in that way, so right now everything is working as was suposed to be, but I still don't know why didn't at the beginning. By the way, I created the file as:
with open(os.path.join(app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR", testFile.txt]), 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')

and it worked. @amanb